# ArcGIS Network analyst - categories of facilities

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, network-analyst

Using the network analyst in ArcMap I am finding 5 closest facilities of each incident.

Is there any chance to work with categories of facilities and find 5 closest facilities that are not in the same category?

For example:  I am trying to find 5 closest pharmacies from a village that is close to a big city "Ahoj". All of the 5 closest pharmacies are in that city "Ahoj" but I want to find only 1 pharmacy from city "Ahoj", then 1 pharmacy from the second closest city, then 1 pharmacy from the third closest city etc.

I can add a printscreen if necessary.